# Convert MySQL rows into columns

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with one column like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
A
B
C
Y
...
```

and I need to convert it into a 4 columns table like this:

```
|  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |
|  5 |  6 |  7 |  A |
|  B |  C |  Y | ...|
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: What have you tried ? How is your table structured ? We do not own crystal balls to guess what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think crystal balls are not necessary. Basically what i'm trying to do is convert one big column table in a 4 columns table maintaining the same order. The table have only one column (varchar,10). Thanks!

Comment: you can't conver your table. make second one and then copy in any order you u wish

Comment: I bit that he wants to make cipher table!

Comment: There is a basic misconception in the phrase ***"maintaining the same order."*** Tables do not have order.

Answer (score 5):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl 
    ADD COLUMN col1 CHAR(1),
    ADD COLUMN col2 CHAR(1),
    ADD COLUMN col3 CHAR(1),
    ADD COLUMN col4 CHAR(1);

SET @rn = 0;

INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2, col3, col4)
SELECT SUBSTRING(GROUP_CONCAT(a.col ORDER BY a.rn), 1, 1),
       SUBSTRING(GROUP_CONCAT(a.col ORDER BY a.rn), 3, 1),
       SUBSTRING(GROUP_CONCAT(a.col ORDER BY a.rn), 5, 1),
       SUBSTRING(GROUP_CONCAT(a.col ORDER BY a.rn), 7, 1)
FROM   (
       SELECT col, @rn:=@rn+1 AS rn
       FROM   tbl
       ) a
GROUP BY CEIL(a.rn / 4);

ALTER TABLE tbl DROP COLUMN col;

DELETE FROM tbl 
WHERE col1 IS NULL AND 
      col2 IS NULL AND
      col3 IS NULL AND 
      col4 IS NULL;
```

---

### [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/675b8/2/2)

Answer (score 0):

if you have php you can try something like this :

```
$q=mysql_query('select col from table');
while ($a=mysql_fetch_assoc($q){
    $c[]=$a['col'];
}
for ($i=0;$d[]=array_slice($c,$i,4););
foreach($d as $k => $v)
  mysql_query("insert into bullsh values('".$v[0]."','".$v[1]."','".$v[2]."','".$v[3]."')");
```